# pdf file will not download

Tags: python, web-scraping, download

For some reason I can't get this to download and the content type is html\text and not pdf. The downloaded pdf file is always very small and when I try to open it the file is corrupted.

````
import request

docketnumber='1'
r = requests.get('https://cases.stretto.com/public/X070/10255/PLEADINGS/1025505242280000000049.pdf', allow_redirects=True, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

print(r.headers.get('content-type'))

open('C:/MyDownloads/' + docketnumber+".pdf", 'wb' ).write(r.content)```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `User-Agent`:

```py
import requests

r = requests.get(
    "https://cases.stretto.com/public/X070/10255/PLEADINGS/1025505242280000000049.pdf",
    allow_redirects=True,
    headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0"
    },
)

with open("1.pdf", "wb") as f_out:
    f_out.write(r.content)
```

Saves `1.pdf`:

```
andrej@andrej:~$ ls -alF 1.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 243976 máj 30 23:03 1.pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

Andrej has the correct answer above but if you want a single OS line:-

```
curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:100.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/100.0" -O https://cases.stretto.com/public/X070/10255/PLEADINGS/1025505242280000000049.pdf
```

result

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  238k  100  238k    0     0   295k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  295k

>1025505242280000000049.pdf
```

[image]